# How detect a program starts on android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to detect a program starts on android.
I know i should code a service and broadcast receiver.the problem is i do not know what intent filter should i use?

EDIT1 :
for example i want to know if user wants to start contact manager.

thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible directly through Intents and service/broadcast receivers as this would constitute a major security issue. Take a look at these other [proposed solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched). The best one would be to replace the launcher if the user allows it.