# Browser started counter

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to count how many times my browser is opened. I guess somehow I need to register a broadcast receiver but I do not know how my intent filter should look like.

I do not want to handle when intent is fired for opening a browser, I just want to be notified about that.

any ideas how can I do that  ?

Comment: by "my browser" do you mean a a browser app that you made?

Comment: tnx for the good note,no I meant the browser that comes installed with the phone

Answer (score 0):

[Android, Detect when other apps are launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched)

What you are asking for has already been discussed, and further I agree with Pontus Gagge on the matter. Why do you want to count the number of times the browser was opened?