# get name of application when user launch this app

Tags: android

I want to create a service (or a broadcast)in my application that detect when the user select any application in the device. So my service will detect that a new application was started.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `getRunningAppProcesses()` to load the list of running apps and check the variation in this list.

see this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses())

another solution is to analyze logcat output

see first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched)

Comment: yes, but i want to get the new running application when it exactly run. i can not check all RunningAppProcesses every time.

Comment: i putted this :
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
   
   List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
   
in my service , in the onStartCommand. and my application was blocked (ANR) Application Not Responding!!!

Comment: ok, in this case you should try to use logcat and analyze it's output in the right way,

see the answer at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched)

Comment: thanks, i have seen this code. But i can't figure out were to put it? can you please help me?
where do we have to put this code? in a service? in the onStartCommand()?