# launch my application when sms is tapped in android

Tags: android, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect when the user launches another app? (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346557/how-to-detect-when-the-user-launches-another-app-android)

I want to do **sms locker** in android. When I click inbox or conversation first **lock screen has to appear** if the password is correct then only inbox should open. how can i do that.

Comment: May I ask why do you want to do it?

Comment: Oh, and take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346557/how-to-detect-when-the-user-launches-another-app-android

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement that you'd have to build your own Messaging application. and have you users use that one instead of the one that comes stock on the device.

The official APIs provide no way for one application to know that another has launched or has taken any particular action (i.e. opening a conversation in sms) without that particular application broadcasting what it is doing (which the stock sms does not do).