# Android:App launch notification

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. I was just looking for any application launch notification on Android. Whenever any other third apps launched on the device, my application should get notified with that app info. Its there in Palm, Windows Mobile and all, just wondering anything like that available on Android. Please suggest me.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346557/how-to-detect-when-the-user-launches-another-app-android/11346771#11346771

Answer (score 0):

To test if you want show notifications, show Dialog in first startup of your application and store the result in the SharedPreferences. If the person select yes : store true in the SharedPreference and subscribe the user in the GCM server to send notifications.

For mor informations about GCM : [Doc Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever any other third apps launched on the device, my application should get notified with that app info.

There is nothing in Android that will notify your application about the launching of other applications.