# Stop launching apps

Tags: java, android

I need some help finding a code for this application I'm working on that is supposed to function as follow:

Whenever the user tries to open an installed application on his phone, he'll be automatically transferred to the home page launcher.

I have the code to get me to the home page launcher, but i need use it whenever the user run an app.

the code:`

```
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(homeIntent);`
```

Comment: Whenever the user tries to start *any* app? I have to ask.. **why**?

Comment: It's a kids mode application for my graduation project.

Comment: What you want to write [already exists](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git).

Comment: No, I want to know whenever an app starts and launch this code.

Comment: some relevant links about cancelling the started process, definitely check the first one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141412/prevent-android-application-from-starting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814696/how-to-kill-currently-running-task-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036895/kill-another-application-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773516/how-to-close-another-app-in-android/3774483#3774483