# Is it possible to listen for when another application is being launched?

Tags: android, launching-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android, Detect when other apps are launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched)

When stock calculator is being launched, I want for my application to be launched over top of it. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible any more, read [Android, Detect when other apps are launched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched).

Comment: it reads like a virus or adware...

Comment: @aldo.roman.nurena I don't know how either one of those read.

Comment: I mean "launch X app when my calculator is launched" could be used to display unwanted ads

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but the application must be running in the background all the time. This will consume memory and battery life.

Also I don't believe that it morally right to force an end user to use your application.

Comment: No my app will only pop up once they enable it and input a pin of their choice. And when they no longer want it to do that, they are more that free to disable it.

Comment: Well in that case, go attempt it. It is possible. Plus this question has been asked before on this site.