# how to detect when user launches anapplication on an Android device

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-launcher

I am trying to develop an application that detect launch of each application which are installed on device.I want to develop same scenario like [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched)

Accroding to it logcat supports only below 4.0(ICS) version and my requirement is for above ICS version.I have seen many application on play store like[Smart appLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.smartlockfree&feature=nav_other#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDYsImNvbS50aGlua3llYWguc21hcnRsb2NrZnJlZSJd).How to create this kind of application which supports all version of android from 2.2 onwards.

Comment: You must maintain a list of currently running apps, check for the change in this list. Bang there is your new app which has been launched!

Answer (score 0):

What I think is that you can keep track of the applications currently running:

```
final   ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
    {
        Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");         
    }
```

Once your polling yealds a new app entry into the list above, you get your desired result.