# Android file operation pause

Tags: android, file-io

I wonder whether it is possibile to **pause a file operation** such as read a file, for example, I have a file named `A.pdf` in **ciphertext**, there is an App--Foxit Reader, want to read the `A.pdf` file, I want to pause the read operation for a while, so that I have time to decrypt the `A.pdf` file, and then pass the plaintext to the Foxit Reader. I wonder whether there is a  way to do this? That is be transparent for the Apps using cipher content. Any ideas?

I don't want to write my own App to do the read operation, I just want to detect the operation, and when an App is reading a specified file under a directory for encrypted files, I just decrypt the file and after read/write, I encrypt the file again. Certaintly, the App that can read/write my file must satisfy some certain conditions I have set, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `Activity` with an `Intent-Filter` for manage the `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` and recive URI file.

At this point you can decrypt the file and save the pdf.

Then start an `Activity` for view the new pdf file OR view the pdf inside your app with [apv library](https://code.google.com/p/apv/).

In the first case you must create a service that clean the directory with your decrypted pdf file.

Comment: I add some content to my issue in the second paragraph.

Comment: i think you could find an input [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched)

Comment: Still not my issue, my purpose is to detect the file read/write operation, and decrypt the file, and after read/write operation, then encrypt the file. What I want is to make the series operation transparent to the App(Foxit Reader for example).

Comment: ok, i think this is not possible.
You can listen the file access with [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) but I doubt you can modify the reading-stream of other apps because you recive the event when the file is already opened.. and you don't have the time to replace the file but give it a try ;)

Comment: Yeah, this is what am concerned, and I am stuck here.