# How to find a user time spent of any android app

Tags: android

Hello I am developing an application where I required to find time spent by user on a certain app like Facebook.

Whenever user has spent x minutes then I want to give some reward to user. Is there any good approach to achieve this in Android ?

Comment: You mean you need to mesure the time spent on **another** application that the one your will be building?

Comment: @shkschneider Yes I want to measure how much user spent time on another apps. If user finish x minutes then I want to give some credit to user.

Comment: You can try reading the log files,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched

Comment: @AcidBurn Unfortunately, this has been disallowed since jellybean. (For non-system apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the question [Detect When other Application opened or Launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500959/detect-when-other-application-opened-or-launched), you cannot listen for other applications launch signals, but you could sample the list of open applications every so often to check if the app you are looking for is a) running and b) in the foreground.

You would have to run this application as a service in the background, and I'm pretty sure that it could have devastating implications on the user's phone battery life.

Comment: If you see applock app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock&hl=en then how they guys do because it doesn't impact much on battery life.

Comment: Emphasize on *could*. It is possible to write the sampler so that it sleeps between updates and preserves battery life: it was more of a "be careful", not a "you can't do this!" ;)

Comment: Well He can listen if the phone screen is on and then doing a sample on open applications. If he don't check every millisecond, I don't think it will be devastating on battery life.

Comment: @Williams This looks like a very reasonable approach.

Comment: @matiash Yup. Looks like a nice idea

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a background `Service` that will check the phone's activity (applications in foreground) and count their active/foreground elapsed time.

**List foreground applications**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

You can detect currently foreground application with `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()`.
It will return a list of `RunningAppProcessInfo` records.

To determine which application is on foreground check `RunningAppProcessInfo.importance` == `RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND`.

**How much time has been spent on it**

`Process.getElapsedCpuTime()` is the best to go IMHO.

*Unfortunately I don't know how to get the `Process` of another application...*

So you could have a looping `Service` incrementing spent time everytime an application is on foreground, but that would not be super precise I'm afraid.

Another way would be to control yourself the opening of those apps and when they leave it and come back to yours, evaluate the spent time in foreground at that moment.

*Just some thoughts, I don't have a complete answer, sorry.*