# Detect which applications have been opened

Tags: android, application-lifecycle

I have such a problem, it is necessary if you run any application to output `Toast` with the text "some application to run," and when closed by show again `Toast` with text "some application is completed."

For example launched `Play Market`, and in my app `Toast` with the text "Play Market is run."

I have no idea how it implemented, it seems necessary to use the Service Broadcast. Please tell me how to implement?

Comment: You want code which monitors the user as they use their device and can detect all the applications they use? That sounds... odd.

Comment: most likely not in an easy way you'd like it to be, whether app-A is running/closing is not exposed to app-B unless app-A itself implements a broadcast... unless you want to continually brute scan active running processes and continually compare.

Comment: "it is necessary" - why? According to who?

Comment: Duplicate anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500959/detect-when-other-application-opened-or-launched

Comment: Simply adding a bounty to your question will not solve your problems. See the links cricket_007 has provided. Do some research

Comment: As of Android 5.0, doing this in a reliable way will be difficult, if not impossible, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare is this a duplicate of those suggested?

Comment: @JonClements: The other questions suggested by cricket_007 are on the same topic, IMHO.

Comment: @CommonsWare were the bounty removed - would you be confident enough it's already solved elsewhere?

Comment: @JonClements: Not for a conventional definition of "solved", IMHO. What is requested is impractical on modern versions of Android. The closest answer out of all of those is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32424365/115145), but since `UsageStatsManager` does not offer real-time data, it cannot be used to solve the problem expressed in this particular question.

Comment: @CommonsWare okay then - is this question answerable in its current form or should it be closed - if so for what reason?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, outside of possible security flaws, there is no reliable way to implement what you want on Android 5.0 and higher, for privacy and security reasons.