# How to count number of times any application opened in my android mobile?

Tags: java, android

I want to develop an android application where it counts the number of times I have opened another application. Say it should count a number of times I have opened Whatsapp or may be Facebook. How can I achieve this through another android application? How to observe the activity, behavior of other applications in android.

Comment: use sharedPreference to count numbers of your application.

Comment: You can't set a listener to check that, however you can check if a app is open so you can get the list of installed apps and then you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500959/detect-when-other-application-opened-or-launched you run this periodically if you detect a certain app you will know that the user launched the app in the past, and you can increment a value in your database

Answer (score 0):

first
 1. create a db  ( `local android SQLite`)

then
 2. get a list of all the installed applications on the device.Use `Android Package Manager` with `getInstalledApplications()`

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d("Installed Apps", "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName + " Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName));
}
```

3. save package names and launcher activities in your db
4. get list of recently launched apps and increment the counter of your db or what you like to do

   ```
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRecentTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE,ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED);

      for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++)
       {

           String LocalApp = recentTasks.get(i).baseIntent.toString();
           int indexPackageNameBegin = LocalApp.indexOf("cmp=")+4;
           int indexPackageNameEnd = LocalApp.indexOf("/", indexPackageNameBegin);
           String pckge = LocalApp.substring(indexPackageNameBegin, indexPackageNameEnd);
           Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " +pckge);
       }
   ```