# How to detect a launch of an application and open my app instead?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Developing an android drive mode application that doesn't allow the user to access other apps when in drive mode. Looking for a way to detect when the user tries to open other apps such as Facebook, twitter, and bring him/her back to my application. Anyone have any ideas? I have been researching for a while with no solution. Is there a way to intercept the activity launch intent by other apps and then dismiss that intent by launching your own application?

Comment: An observation: If I want to open Facebook, I want to open Facebook. I don't want some other application muscling in and forcing me to run BookFace (or whatever) instead. I don't know that I've clearly understood your intent, but I'm pretty sure that whatever your app is, I don't want it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched

Comment: @MikeW this application will only be used when the user is driving to prevent him/her from being distracted and getting into accidents. If there is a way to just block the messaging app that would be useful too.

Comment: @Naddy Thank you. I came across this link as well but the solution seems outdated. My application is targeting jellybean and higher versions of Android.