# Android start ActivityRecognition Manually

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition, android-intentservice

my Android App needs to detect the current Activity (running, walking, ...).

I followed the instructions on the Android Dev Page:
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionClient.html

```
// Connect to the ActivityRecognitionService
ActivityRecognitionClient mActivityRecognitionClient =
       new ActivityRecognitionClient(this, this, this);
mActivityRecognitionClient.connect();

// Called when a connection to the ActivityRecognitionService has been established.
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
   PendingIntent callbackIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
           PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   mActivityRecognitionClient.requestActivityUpdates(30000, callbackIntent);
}
```

And in my Intent-Service:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
   if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
       ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
       // Put your application specific logic here (i.e. result.getMostProbableActivity())
   }
}
```

**Here's my problem**: I want to start the activity recognition on my own. The Code from the Android Dev Page seems, like it's supposed to do that. BUT if I don't add the service to the AndroidManifest, it won't do anything. The onConnected() method gets called, but not onHandleIntent().

So I thought I might just need to add it to the Manifest. Now I do receive Activities, but I receive them all the time. This is also not what I want. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Steff

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do it "manually", without `google-play-services`.
See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched/22303460#22303460). The main idea is to detect current top `Activity`, which is `Activity` of external application. You can create `Service`, which will monitor top activities.

Comment: Thanks, but I still hope to find a solution with which I can use the logic given by Android. Why would I call `mActivityRecognitionClient.connect();`if there was no chance to start the recognition programatically. If I add the service to the manifest, I don't even call that function and it still works.