# How to receive the Intent when an app starts

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I know the android broadcasts an Intent to start an activity. I can use a Broadcast Receiver to receive that intent. But what is the actual way of receiving an intent if an app starts in Android as I don't know what can be the actual intent for an app be (Means I can get the list of installed android applications but how to know what intent will be broadcasted if a particular app starts) .

EDIT :

I'm just adding this as a feature in my phone that if a game launches, then the Immersive mode will automatically be opened. I've system priveleges as well (as I can make the changes in SystemUI or frameworks as well). I don't want to touch the Launcher though.

Answer (score 0):

by this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched) . But it's still a little bit weird as solution . I don't think there's any simple way to do it...