# Intercept Android's explicit intents

Tags: android, android-intent

It's the first time I post here, and I am a non-native speaker. So please forgive me if there is any bad grammar.

I am working on a project that wants to detect this:
When an app A sends some data to another app B and app B behaves abnormally after receiving the data, the app I wrote should send an notification to users.
For example, app B's memory usage suddenly shoots up to, say, 50%.

However, after searching, I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched) that says it is impossible to detect/intercept explicit intent sent between apps.

Does that mean I have no way to tell whether two apps communicate with each other?

ps: I know  that it is possible to detect implicit intents, but that's not what I want.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As you suggested, there is no way to tell whether two apps communicate with each other, so what you're asking simply isn't possible.