# How to fetch application details which has just started in android

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to track a certain app after it has installed. I want to have a information of apps whenever they start.

It's just like `AppLock` app in which they know when I open an app on which I activated a lock then it show their `activity` to enter password.

To achieve this 
I've made a service and put a while loop infinite in a gap of 1 seconds to keep track of running application on top but it really drain my battery in a few hours. `AppLock` did this in a nice way that's why it doesn't drain battery fast.

I know that my current logic that is really bad:

```
while(true) {
    final   ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " +recentTasks.get(0).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(0).id+"");         
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

### Question

How this should be done in a efficient way as like `AppLock` app ?

Comment: Umm. not a solution, but as a work around, you can try to use this code only when device screen is ON. with a broadcast receiver for `android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON`. And if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7239840/1777090) makes sense, you can try

Answer (score 0):

There is an Action called `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED`.

So add an Broadcast reciver like

```
    <receiver android:name="your.package.PackageRestartedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Add your `onRecive` function and you are good to go.

Comment: I added this in my application then I open the facebook then this broadcast receiver is not getting called. I removed this `            <data android:scheme="package"/>` not sure what to write in package.

Comment: idk this answer is correct or not, but this answer means you should write `your.package.PackageRestartedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver` class. and `<data android:scheme="package"/>` does not need to change.

Comment: @ytRino I did but this never execute :(