# How do I make a alert message when a particular Android app starts opening

Tags: java, android

How do I make my background process of my app make a alert message when a particular specified app with a package name started opening.

I want my background process to fire a alert message when a some other apps gets open.

Comment: unless your app is a launcher app you dont know when or what app is opened

Comment: Can you provide more details about what exactly you want to do as this is somewhat vague

Comment: Check for currently launched application in loop (by 100-300ms), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched