# Adding activity/fragment when user opens any application on android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to add a particular activity (suppose ask password) when user opens any application. How can i do this in android?

-For example: Suppose user wants to open camera, it should be redirected first to that password screen, user will add password and if it is right he would be able to open camera.

Comment: If its only about checking password : Instead of starting Activity/Fragment your can show Custom DialogBox with EditText (to enter password).

Comment: Simply open prefence dialog for password instead of call a activity.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

Comment: Hi You can do it by checking the currently running application process. I do not think there is any options for listen the any third party application is being launched.  For that you have to implement the service in smart way  without draining the battery and much load memory. I had implemented the similar points few year ago it works cool in all devices. just only keep in mind that you should test lot in different test case and inform you application to inform for open the password activity/dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to declare a background service to capture the event when camera application is opened by the user. Background service will have onReceive() method. In that method, you can get the list of running applications processes and match that if the camera is in the foreground. If the camera is clicked by the user, it will appear in the list of the running applications. Then you intercept that event and show the dialog fragment you intend to show to the user.

You can implement a custom DialogFragment class which has required field for asking user the password.

In the Custom dialog class you declare an interface, something like this:

```
public interface CustomAddressDialogListener{
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, String enteredPassword);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}
```

Custom DialogFragment will have its own layout for entering the password and you can set Positive actions and negative actions.

Positive action: user enters password and hits submit.

Negative action: user doesn't want to enter password and clicks cancel.

Your parent activity can implement this interface to capture positive and negative click.

```
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, String enteredPassword) {
// Here you can check if the password is correct or wrong and take the action accordingly to open the camera.
}
```

While handling the negative action you can kill the camera process using kill the camera process: android.os.Process.sendSignal(pid, android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
Here pid is the process id of the camera application. You can obtain pid when you obtains information of running application processes.

For details you can refer to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: So again a doubt, how can i apply it over other applications like camera?

Comment: One more thing is we can use accessibility service also!