# How to detect an app is going to start

Tags: android

I want to know is there any way to know an app is going to start, I'm planning to write a simple app that logs usage time of app since its start to its stop, Then I can log time of that app was is foreground. Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, Detect when other apps are launched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched)

Comment: Will not work from JellyBean and above. READ_LOGS permission is now reserved for system apps only

Comment: then probably you will need root access to do so