# Can I make a app to register usage of others apps in device?

Tags: android

Sample:

**Today** 
facebook - 2 hours
email - 1 hours
Candy crush - 45 minutes

Is there any service that give me this information ?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to parse the logs to get this information. Your app would need to the android.permission.READ_LOGS permission. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7239840/1943229).

In Android 5.0 and newer you can use the [UsageStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/package-summary.html) to get this information.