# Date and time of the applications last launch

Tags: android, package-managers

In my application, you need to get the date and time of the all applications last  launch on the device. Can I somehow get this information by standard means?

Comment: you can get last launch app name but not last date time ,you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched

Answer (score 0):

Just save the time on every launch

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
long lastLaunchMillis = sharedPref.getLong("lastLaunch", 0);
if (lastLaunchMillis != 0) {
    Calendar lastLaunch = Calendar.getInstance();
    lastLaunch.setTimeInMillis(lastLaunchMillis);
    //last launch found, handle
}
sharedPref.edit().putLong("lastLaunch", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()).apply();
```

---

**Edit**: For launch statistics of other apps, have a look at [`UsageStatsManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html). You can find a sample on its usage [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppUsageStatistics).

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know the time of the last launch of not only my application, but also other installed ones.

Comment: Your link helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: The link is only for >=`lollipop` devices . What about pre-lollipop devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with creating an Application class and set it from your app's manifest file. Step by step:

1. Create a class extends `Application`:

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends Application {

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();

           // save date to sharedpref
           PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).
               edit().putLong("LAST_LAUNCH_DATE_MS", new Date().getTime()).apply();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Set it to your app from manifest file:

   ```
   <application
       android:name="com.my.project.MyApplication"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
       .....
       .....
   </application>
   ```

You can get last launch time as milliseconds from `SharedPreferences` now.

Comment: That will not "get the date and time of **all** applications last launch on the device" (emphasis added).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Object var10000 = this.getSystemService(USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) var10000;
            Log.d("TAG", "" + usageStatsManager);

            List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(INTERVAL_DAILY, currentTime - (long) 600000, currentTime);
            Log.d("TAG", "" + queryUsageStats);
long last_used;
for(i=0 , i<queryUsageStats  , i++){
 last_used = queryUsageStats .get(i).getLastTimeUsed();
                    Log.d("tag", "" + queryUsageStats );
}
```

here is the way you can do that, you will get time in epos time so you have to convert it to normal time format.