# How to get package name of any app when it gets opened by user?

Tags: android, package, tracking

I need to get **package name** or **app name** of any app when it gets opened by user. I searched about this but didn't get proper example.

Anyone can give me suggestions for this case?
Thank you so much.!

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched)

Comment: Do you mean in your App? When someone open other application, it will store in your App List?

Comment: yes, I wanted to ask if there was a broadcast or anything similar that I could listen to and when the app was opened it would send me information. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your background service for that , which will continuously monitor top app in device .

So first of all make a service which will start after your app launch .In your service , use this

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
activityOnTop=ar.topActivity.getClassName();
```

**activityOnTop** will give you the current running app in your phone . Now do whatever you want after getting top activity.

Comment: I also found the same answer, but I wanted to ask if there was a broadcast or anything similar that I could listen to and when the app was opened it would send me information. Thanks

Comment: @TrungĐoan what you want to do actually ?

Comment: I want to know the package name when the user opens any app,

As I Know from android L, RunningTaskInfo is deprecated and instead can use RunningAppProcessInfo.

But when i using RunningAppProcessInfo in samsing device, it can get only my package name.

Comment: @TrungĐoan  this is exactly mentioned in the answer . make service , run it in background , put that code in it . and you will get your package name

Comment: I found a component that helped me solve this problem. I use AccessibilityService to detect WINDOW STATE CHANGED and it works well for me.
Thank you for your support.