# Popup when opening an app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-development

Is it possible to programm an app that runs in the background and get the information when you open an app, checks if its a special app (f.ex. youtube) and then get a popup/ push? Or does this already exists?

Comment: You better create a LauncherApp and handle if the user click in any installed application trough it. Else you may be looking for BroadcastReceiver if there's any broadcast for 3rd apps launches

Comment: BUT... the broadcastreceiver solution wouldnt enable you to block a application from being launched anyway while the LauncherApp (that the user would use as a HomeLauncher) can

Comment: See this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched