# Can an android application be open when another app open?

Tags: android

I want to create an app can help me control my Facebook addiction and waste time on my phone. So I want to create an android application start when I open an app like Facebook or Twitter , when I open Facebook, my app will start timing and tell me after a time that I setting in it. Can I do that, or should I run my app on the background. I'm new to android so I don't know where to find information or keyword to research.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: there are already so many apps which are doing that like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zerodesktop.appdetox.qualitytime, so yeah it is possible ,may be they are running some background services which keeps track of time of every app usage

Comment: but what technique they use you can you tell me some keyword to search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there is no direct way of doing it, but you have to figure out the solution for that by running a service and accessing stats

refer this thread for detail
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched)

this particular latest answer on that

[latest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32424365/4116758)

you may have to figure out a solution for that and its possible, many apps are doing it.

upvoted your question, because i liked the question and idea. Please post back the best solution you implement, so that someone in the future might benefit of it and the i guess few of the solutions given are already outdated now.

Comment: I will try the code in that question and feedback my result for you, thank you sir.