# Can i detect, when some other application open by user?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to build an app like app locker.How can i get an event, when user opens an app. Please help me with this.

Comment: The question already has many answers. like this e.g
[Android, Detect when other apps are launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched)

Comment: These given answers is not working for new android API. Please help me with this.

Comment: This amount of information makes a multitude of follow-up questions inevitable, so try and help speed up that process by providing more specific detail about what you've already tried, with code examples preferably. The easier you make it to answer the faster and more readily you'll get them.