# Run code when specified app is on foreground

Tags: java, c#, android, android-studio, xamarin.forms

NOTE: I'm using either Java or C# (Xamarin.Forms), whichever is the easiest. I'd prefer Java, but if I could do the same in Xamarin.Forms that's fine as well.

I want to run code when a specified app is launched (Or in foreground but preferably launched).

E.g when app Facebook is launched Toast "Facebook" or "App launched". What do I want to do with this? When a specified app is launched, I want to turn down/up the volume on the device.

Thanks.

Comment: Well in my knowledge this cannot be done in a direct way. What you can do is check the logcat BUT that only works pre-jelly bean.

Comment: Hmm that would not be an option. Are you aware of any other options? I know other apps that can do it.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched

Comment: Apparently that only works for Jelly Bean and lower