# Android: How to detect if user exits activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to know when a user exits a certain activity, such as by:
- Navigating to another activity within the same app
- Exiting the app
- Putting the phone to sleep

What are ways to detect the above, and maybe other possibilities?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843911/android-detect-when-another-activity-is-launched-or-your-activity-loses-focus

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use LifeCycle events such as onDestroy() or onStop()
you can override them in your activity

Comment: You can also user onUserLeaveHint() I believe. Very good for detecting when the user leaves the app.